# installation of CommCare HQ on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

Trying to install/configure [CommCare HQ](http://www.commcarehq.org/home/) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I've installed all dependencies, set them up and running, when I entered the command

```
 ./manage.py syncdb --noinput
```

show the followings error:

```
INFO Raven is not configured (disabled). Please see documentation for more information.
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
sync `auditcare` in CouchDB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 30, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
.
.
.
.
raise RequestError("socket.error: %s" % str(e))
restkit.errors.RequestError: socket.error: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

please guide me way to come out of this error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your couchdb settings may not have been setup correctly. You should make sure the following settings in your localsettings point to the right database:

```
####### Couch Config ######
COUCH_HTTPS = False # recommended production value is True if enabling https
COUCH_SERVER_ROOT = '127.0.0.1:5984'
COUCH_USERNAME = 'admin'
COUCH_PASSWORD = '********'
COUCH_DATABASE_NAME = 'commcarehq'
```

https://github.com/dimagi/commcare-hq has pretty solid installation instructions that should work on Ubuntu 12.04